# Ternary operator with string concatination causes partial loss of content?

Tags: java

```
Boolean isValid = true;
String message = "prefix" + isValid != null ? " midfix " : "suffix";
System.out.println(message);
```

What do you think is the result of this? I'd expect `prefix midfix`. But actually the result is: `midfix`!

Is this an error in the java library itself (1.7)? Should I report a bug for this? Or does this work as intended, and I'm misusing it?

It can be "fixed" using:

`String message = "prefix" + (isValid != null ? " midfix " : "suffix");`
but anyways shouldn't it work without the brakets?

Comment: ("prefix"+isValid) != null

Comment: That's about operator precedence..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is evaluated as :

```
String message = (("prefix" + isValid) != null) ? " midfix " : "suffix";
```

which is equivalent to :

```
String message = ("prefixtrue" != null) ? " midfix " : "suffix";
```

Therefore "midfix" is returned.

If you wish "prefix midfix" to be returned use parentheses:

```
String message = "prefix" + (isValid != null ? " midfix " : "suffix");
```